# Python: Check if file was saved

Tags: python, blend-files

I want to be able to check if the working .blend file has been saved when a user presses a button. If it has not been, Blender should give an error.

I just want the user to save before running my add-on.

Comment: @RayMairlot  I don't quite understand why this isn't specifically about Blender, as he is asking how to determine (from within *Blender*, using *Blender's* UI) if a *Blender* file has been saved.

Comment: @PGmath I don't think it's relevant that it's done within Blender and I didn't see the button press as a core part of the question (there are other questions already on this). As shown by the answer below, the answer is a purely python (not bpy) solution.

Comment: @PGmath I guess I may be misunderstanding the question as it's unclear if the 'file' they're referencing is a blender file and if they mean has it been saved since changes have been made or if the file isn't saved at all. Confirmation from OP would be helpful.

Comment: @RayMairlot  The former was my impression.  So OP please add some further clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If 'the file' you are referencing is a blender file and you want to know if it has been saved then there are two properties you can check.

If a blender file hasn't been saved at all you can check it's `is_saved` property as this will be `False` if it hasn't been saved:

```
if bpy.data.is_saved:
    #File has been saved. Do something.
```

(A previous version of this answer instead checked if the [`filepath`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.filepath) property was blank instead - the above is a correction thanks to [poor's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58711/python-check-if-file-was-saved/58728?noredirect=1#comment101121_58728)).

For files that have been saved you can check the `is_dirty` property, which will be `True` when changes have been made since the last save:

```
if bpy.data.is_dirty:
    #Changes have been made since the last save. Do something.
```

To get a button to execute code have a look at [Simple way to add button to UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/simple-way-to-add-button-to-ui).

For error messages look at [Proper way to show users error info in the UI for addons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/proper-way-to-show-users-error-info-in-the-ui-for-addons).

Comment: This is just what I needed. I already know how to add a button.

Comment: Nitpicking: Using [`is_saved`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.is_saved) flag is probably the better option to check if the file is saved - `Has the current session been saved to disk as a .blend file` If you really like to go with `filepath` the comparison operator is not necessary here. You can write `if not bpy.data.filepath:` to check an empty string, that's easier to understand and more pythonic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9573259/3091066

Comment: @poor Thanks, don't know how I missed that option but I'll add it in. Also didn't know about the empty string, that's a great tip.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make Ray's answer more specific with my question:

The code should be

```
if bpy.data.is_dirty:
    print("You must save your file!")
else:
    print("File OK!")
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really a blender question, but more a python question. But anyway, this would do the trick:

```
from os.path import isfile

if not isfile( PathOfSavedFile ): # Check if file exists
    raise IOError( "file <%s> not saved" % PathOfSavedFile )
```